# Checkout to previous than head without revision number

Tags: svn

I'm dealing with bunch of repositories (managed by subversion), in which all of them have their own head revision number. I need to checkout all over again to one revision before the head. Is it possible to use some svn syntax that would allow me to checkout without using a specific revision number? I.e. svn co -r PREV https://svn...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure it is not possible in one simple command line.
I suggest you to do with 2 command lines as follows:

```
svn co https://svn/repository
svn up -r PREV
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a single command to do this, but you can calculate the appropriate revision number.  If you have the URL of your repository stored in the variable `repo`, then you can do:

```
# Check out repository one *revision* before HEAD
rev=$(svn info $repo | grep "^Revision" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
svn co $repo -r $(($rev - 1)) .

# Check out repository one *change* before HEAD
rev=$(svn info $repo | grep "^Last Changed Rev" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
svn co $repo -r $(($rev - 1)) .
```

If the previous revision changed something in a different branch than the one that you're checking out, then these two commands can give you very different results.  Use whichever version is appropriate for your task (it's not completely clear from the question).

Checking out HEAD and using `svn update` to back up a revision is essentially equivalent to the "last change" version above.  The version above can be more efficient if the last change touches a large number of files because it only downloads them once (as opposed to downloading their HEAD version, then re-downloading their HEAD-1 version).